# Update TextView height after setting font with setTypeface on Android

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I'm setting font of a `TextView` using `setTypeface()` method.

Unfortunately, after the font of the text view is changed, the `TextView` usually remains of the same size as previously. If the new font is slightly wider than the original one, the `TextView` may become 1 line longer, but the layout doesn't get updated. In some cases I've seen 2-line text views getting cropped from the bottom because of this.

If the `TextView` is inside a `ScrollView`, a 2-line `TextView` may be displayed as 1-line with a scroller even though there is enough space to just show it as 2 lines without scrolling.

Apparently, the OS forgets to update the height of the `TextView` if it becomes 1 line longer after a typeface change.

Is there any workaround for this? Can I trigger an update of height of `TextView` manually right after setting the new font?

Thanks!

I'm calling `txt.setTypeface(someFont);` right after `setContentView()`

neither `txt.requestLayout()` nor `txt.forceLayout()` helped.

Comment: Have you tried view.requestLayout(); or view.forceLayout(); ?

Comment: Just tried, but it didn't help. Am I doing something wrong? (updated the question)